# Referring to a static variable from a static method of the same class

Tags: php, oop

You have a static function:

> public static function foo()

In the same class you have a static variable:

```
public static $uaa
```

How do you refer to $uaa from foo()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this: `self::$uaa`